# Makefile and docker attach. How to execute from other Makefile's task?

Tags: bash, docker, makefile

I have a Makefile:

```
attach:
    docker run --rm \
        -it \
        alpine:3.8

run-inside: attach
    uname -a
```

I can run `make attach` and type `uname -a` by hands

*`uname -a`, is just for example*

I want `run-inside` to run container, attach to it, execute command and stop container. Is it possible to do this? I need this because i'm setting up CI for my project, and i need to know how to run without copy/paste

I know i can do this:

```
run:
    docker run --rm \
        alpine:3.8 uname -a
```

But this way i'm duplicating docker command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution consists in using the `-d` (`--detach`) option of [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/), along with the [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec) command.

For example:

> Makefile

```
IMAGE ?= alpine:3.8
NAME ?= foobar
RUN = docker exec $(NAME)

all: start run-inside stop

start:
    docker run -d -i --name=$(NAME) --rm --init $(IMAGE)

run-inside:
    $(RUN) cat /etc/os-release
    $(RUN) uname -a

stop:
    docker stop $(NAME)

.PHONY: all start run-inside stop
```

Regarding the options passed to `docker run`:

- `-d` tells the Docker Engine to run the container in the background;
- `-i` is necessary to keep the container running (while `-t` is useless here);
- `--name` specifies the container's name;
- `--rm` triggers the container's removal as soon as it is stopped (here, with `docker stop`);
- `--init` is optional (it is especially handy when the *entrypoint* is a shell, so that the signal sent by `docker stop` can be processed immediately by the [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) process, run as PID 1).

As an aside, relying on a Makefile is maybe unnecessary when configuring a Docker-based CI: it can work well but you might instead want to:

- inline the `docker` commands at stake directly in a `.travis.yml` or `.gitlab-ci.yml` or so;
- use a [docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) file and install `docker-compose` beforehand.